# unfollow js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZECEN/100/)

I'm working on follow and unfollow buttons. Follow option is working fine but when I click on unfollow it does not turn into follow. Full code posted on JsFiddle

```
$(".follow").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $button = $(this);
    if($button.hasClass('unfollow')){

        //$.ajax(); Do Unfollow

        $button.removeClass('follow');
        $button.removeClass('unfollow');
        $button.text('Follow');
    } 
    else {

        // $.ajax(); Do Follow

        $button.addClass('follow');
        $button.text('Unfollow');
    } });
```

Comment: You're checking for click event using `$(".follow").live('click'`

Comment: And I thought that unfollow js is some kind of new library :)

Comment: OP Better mark [anandnat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317036#22317072)  as answer .He has wriiten it the code first .I posted it late.I didn't notice it as it didn't showed any answer due to slow net speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(this)
.text( ($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'UnFollow' : 'Follow') )
.toggleClass("Unfollow");
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZECEN/103/)**

Comment: +1 This should be the selected answer... Can't believe the other guy stole it AND got his selected.

Answer (score 1):

To get the both classes toggling, this is the easiest approach:

```
$button.toggleClass('unfollow').toggleClass('follow');
```

And the button has either specified:

```
<button class="follow">
```

or

```
<button class="unfollow">
```

And for the button text you'd need something like this (after the toggle chain above):

```
$button.text($button.hasClass('follow') ? 'follow' : 'unfollow');
```

And you'd need listeners for both `follow` and `unfollow` classes (you forgot that).

So, the whole code should look like this (note the use of `on()`):

```
 $("body").on('click', ".follow, .unfollow", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $button = $(this); 
     $button.toggleClass('unfollow').toggleClass('follow');
     $button.text($button.hasClass('follow') ? 'follow' : 'unfollow'); 
 });
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZECEN/110/

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/bK6A8/)

```
 $(".follow").live('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $button = $(this);
     if ($button.hasClass('unfollow')) {

         //$.ajax(); Do Unfollow

         $button.addClass('follow'); //changed here to addClass follow
         $button.removeClass('unfollow');
         $button.text('Follow');
     } else {

         // $.ajax(); Do Follow

         $button.addClass('unfollow');//changed here to addClass unfollow
         $button.text('Unfollow');
     }
 });
```

---

Better use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/bK6A8/1)

```
$button.text( ($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'UnFollow' : 'Follow') ).toggleClass("Unfollow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code to this:

```
$(".follow").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("Unfollow").text(($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'UnFollow' : 'Follow'))
});
```

Also note that `live()` is deprecated as of version `1.7`, you should use `on()` instead.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZECEN/106/)**

Answer (score 0):

`live()` is deprecated, you could just bind the event on the button element.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('follow')
           .toggleClass('unfollow')
           .text(function() {
               return $(this).hasClass('follow') ? 'Follow' : 'Unfollow';
            });
});
```

***[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZECEN/105/)***